# how to import products in bulk in hybris promotion rule

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to add a condition to the hybris promotion rule for products that qualify and I want to be able to bulk import a list of products into this rule

bulk import products for this promotion rule condition

how to make it

Comment: I strongly suggest to use categories for this purpose.